# Why are my walls invisible from the back?

Tags: java, 3d

I'm currently working on a Java project which deals with creating a 3D maze game, but I have an issue with the walls. Indeed,when we walk around a wall, it disappears; it's like the wall can't be seen from the back.

Here is my code (mainly from YouTube user "[thecherno](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheChernoProject)"):

```
public void renderWall(double xLeft, double xRight, double zDistanceLeft, double zDistanceRight, double yHeight) {
    double upCorrect = 0.0625;
    double rightCorrect = 0.0625;
    double forwardCorrect = 0.0625;
    double walkCorrect = -0.0625;

    /* que se passe t-il quand on bouge vers la gauche sur l'axe des x */
    double xcLeft = ((xLeft) - (right * rightCorrect)) * 2;
    /* sur la gauche sur l'axe des z */
    double zcLeft = ((zDistanceLeft) - (forward * forwardCorrect)) * 2;

    /* quand on fait une rotation vers la gauche sur l'axe des x */
    double rotLeftSideX = xcLeft * cosine - zcLeft * sine;
    /* le coin du mur haut gauche */
    double yCornerTL = ((-yHeight) - (-up * upCorrect + (walking * walkCorrect))) * 2;
    /* bas gauche */
    double yCornerBL = ((+0.5 - yHeight) - (-up * upCorrect + (walking * walkCorrect))) * 2;
    /* quand on fait une rotation vers la gauche sur l'axe des z */
    double rotLeftSideZ = zcLeft * cosine + xcLeft * sine;

    /* Pour la droite */
    double xcRight = ((xRight) - (right * rightCorrect)) * 2;
    double zcRight = ((zDistanceRight) - (forward * forwardCorrect)) * 2;

    double rotRightSideX = xcRight * cosine - zcRight * sine;
    double yCornerTR = ((-yHeight) - (-up * upCorrect + (walking * walkCorrect))) * 2;
    double yCornerBR = ((+0.5 - yHeight) - (-up * upCorrect + (walking * walkCorrect))) * 2;
    double rotRightSideZ = zcRight * cosine + xcRight * sine;

    double tex30 = 0;
    double tex40 = 8;
    double clip = 0.5;
    if (rotLeftSideZ < clip && rotRightSideZ < clip) {
        return;
    }
    if (rotLeftSideZ < clip) {
        double clip0 = (clip - rotLeftSideZ) / (rotRightSideZ - rotLeftSideZ);
        rotLeftSideZ = rotLeftSideZ + (rotRightSideZ - rotLeftSideZ) * clip0;
        rotLeftSideX = rotLeftSideX + (rotRightSideX - rotLeftSideX) * clip0;
        tex30 = tex30 + (tex40 - tex30) * clip0;
    }
    if (rotRightSideZ < clip) {
        double clip0 = (clip - rotLeftSideZ) / (rotRightSideZ - rotLeftSideZ);
        rotRightSideZ = rotLeftSideZ + (rotRightSideZ - rotLeftSideZ) * clip0;
        rotRightSideX = rotLeftSideX + (rotRightSideX - rotLeftSideX) * clip0;
        tex40 = tex30 + (tex40 - tex30) * clip0;
    }


    double xPixelLeft = (rotLeftSideX / rotLeftSideZ * height + width / 2);
    double xPixelRight = (rotRightSideX / rotRightSideZ * height + width / 2);

    /* si le coté gauche du mur passe au dela du coté droit */
    if (xPixelLeft >= xPixelRight) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * On cast les double en entier car les pixels sont placé dans un
     * tableau d'entier
     */
    int xPixelLeftInt = (int) (xPixelLeft);
    int xPixelRightInt = (int) (xPixelRight);

    /* Si ca depasse, on rend rien */
    if (xPixelLeftInt < 0) {
        xPixelLeftInt = 0;
    }
    if (xPixelRightInt > width) {
        xPixelRightInt = width;
    }

    double yPixelLeftTop = (yCornerTL / rotLeftSideZ * height + height / 2.0);
    double yPixelLeftBottom = (yCornerBL / rotLeftSideZ * height + height / 2.0);
    double yPixelRightTop = (yCornerTR / rotRightSideZ * height + height / 2.0);
    double yPixelRightBottom = (yCornerBR / rotRightSideZ * height + height / 2.0);

    double tex1 = 1 / rotLeftSideZ;
    double tex2 = 1 / rotRightSideZ;
    double tex3 = 0 / rotLeftSideZ;
    double tex4 = 8 / rotRightSideZ - tex3;

    for (int x = xPixelLeftInt; x < xPixelRightInt; x++) {

        double pixelRotation = (x - xPixelLeft) / (xPixelRight - xPixelLeft);
        double zWall = (tex1 + (tex2 - tex1) * pixelRotation);

        if(zBufferWall[x] > zWall){
            continue;
        }

        zBufferWall[x] = zWall;
        int xTexture = (int) ((tex3 + tex4 * pixelRotation) / (tex1 + (tex2 - tex1) * pixelRotation));

        double yPixelTop = yPixelLeftTop + (yPixelRightTop - yPixelLeftTop) * pixelRotation;
        double yPixelBottom = yPixelLeftBottom + (yPixelRightBottom - yPixelLeftBottom) * pixelRotation;

        int yPixelTopInt = (int) (yPixelTop);
        int yPixelBottomInt = (int) (yPixelBottom);

        /* Si ca depasse, on rend rien */
        if (yPixelTopInt < 0) {
            yPixelTopInt = 0;
        }
        if (yPixelBottomInt > height) {
            yPixelBottomInt = height;
        }

        for (int y = yPixelTopInt; y < yPixelBottomInt; y++) {
            double pixelRotationY = (y - yPixelTop) / (yPixelBottom - yPixelTop);
            int yTexture = (int) (8 * pixelRotationY);
            // pixels[x + y * width] = xTexture * 100 + yTexture * 100 *
            // 256;
            pixels[x + y * width] = Texture.floor.pixels[(xTexture & 7) + 8 + (yTexture & 7) * 16];
            zBuffer[x + y * width] = 1 / (tex1 + (tex2 - tex1) * pixelRotation) * 8;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem come from this:

```
if (xPixelLeft >= xPixelRight) {
    return;
}
```

Why does the code include lines that cause walls to disappear, and how should I make walls visible from both sides?

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. I've edited it so that it asks what I think you wanted to know.

Comment: moved issue to the beginning of the question

Answer (score 0):

This is [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling), a technique which removes surfaces that (normally) wouldn't be visible because they're on the far side of opaque objects. (Think of a cube: you can only see three faces of it at once.) This allows the program to be faster because it does less work.

You have two main options, I think:

- Remove the lines you identified: this will make all the surfaces double-sided, so that they are drawn regardless of which way they face. Note that the walls will be extremely thin, with textures mirrored on the other side.
- Add extra (single-sided) surfaces on the other side, in those places that need them. This allows you to use different textures and lighting on each side, and you can separate the surfaces so that the walls have thickness.

You can also use variations on these, such as adding extra surfaces in some places and marking others double-sided, or switching to another texture when drawing back-faces.

By the way, try setting [noclip mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noclip_mode) in a game and flying outside where you're normally limited to: you may see these and related techniques in use. For instance, in some games the sky is only drawn within windows or on a 'ceiling' over outdoor areas.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the cube point. I believe (for a cube) that 6 sides are rendered but (because of backface culling) if you were inside the cube you wouldn't see it

Answer (score 0):

Thanx you deltab.

I've write down this code :

```
    if (xPixelLeft >= xPixelRight) {
          double e = xPixelLeft;
          xPixelLeft = xPixelRight;
          xPixelRight = e;
          e = rotLeftSideX;
          rotLeftSideX = rotRightSideX;
          rotRightSideX = e;
          e = yCornerTL;
          yCornerTL = yCornerTR;
          yCornerTR = e;
          e = yCornerBL;
          yCornerBL = yCornerBR;
          yCornerBR = e;

          e = yPixelLeftTop;
          yPixelLeftTop = yPixelRightTop;
          yPixelRightTop = e;
          e = yPixelLeftBottom;
          yPixelLeftBottom = yPixelRightBottom;
          yPixelRightBottom = e;
    }
```

And it works !
I'll now work on the colision problem which will be a big part...